# How to add time delay in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, timer

Now I have to demo how the sort code work on Java `JFrame` but the problem is I don't know how to make the delay between the switch.

How can I add the delay when mark the column with color? Already searched on many threads but I'm too newbie to know how the code work with Swing timer.

```
public void MarkColumn(JLabel column) { 
        column.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 0)); 
        //Delay 1.5 seconds; 

    } 

public void UnmarkColumn(JLabel column) { 
        column.setBackground(new Color(51, 153, 255)); 
        //Delay 1.5 seconds; 
    } 

public void BubbleSort() 
    { 
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) { 
                    MarkColumn(columns.get(i)); 
                    for (int j = list.size() - 1; j > i; j--) { 
                        MarkColumn(columns.get(j)); 
                        if (list.get(j).getPoint() < list.get(j - 1).getPoint()) { 
                            SinhVien tg = list.get(j - 1); 
                            list.set(j - 1, list.get(j)); 
                            list.set(j, tg); 
                        } 
                        UnmarkColumn(columns.get(j)); 
                    } 
                    UnmarkColumn(columns.get(i)); 
                } 
    }
```

Comment: 1) Use a one shit Swing based `Timer` 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: 1) That's why I asking a question here, I dont know how to use Timer T_T.
3) Still learning java here. Thanks for the tips anyway.

Comment: So fix 3) & attend to 2) - showing your best effort to use a `Timer`.

Comment: `I dont know how to use Timer` - search the forum or the web for examples. Start with simple examples. Then when you understand the basics you can try to implement it in your code. The first example I ever used was just to update a JLabel with the time every second.